# Muscat to Penang via Kuala Lumpur

Tags: airports, layovers, kul

I will be travelling from Muscat (Oman) to Penang (Malaysia) with a layover in Kuala Lumpur. The first flight is operated by Oman Air and arrives at Terminal M. After a layover of few hours, the second flight departs from the same Terminal M and is operated by Malaysian Airlines.

1. Do I have to pass through immigration or can I catch the Malaysian Airlines flight directly for Penang?
2. I need to collect the boarding pass for Penang from Kuala Lumpur airport as I am travelling in two different airlines.

Comment: Are the two flights in one reservation? or separate? could you do an online check-in for penang sector?

Comment: Yes, both the flights are in one reservation, but vendor locator are different.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**: KL to Penang is a domestic flight, so you will have clear Malaysian immigration in KL, pick up your bags, take them through Customs, and check in for your connecting flight.  You should allow at least 2 hours for this, more if you have separate tickets.

Note that "Terminal M" simply means the main terminal (KLIA1).   Odds are pretty high you'll land in the satellite terminal, with immigration and your connecting flight in the main building, but the two are connected with a train shuttle (Aerotrain).

Comment: @RajanMandoliyil Please accept the answer (click the check mark) if it worked for you!